# console.log is rendered twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, console.log

i have problem, im starting with Hooks Methods in React, i have a input search that when i press the key "Enter", this join into a function that set the value. the problem is when i try to return the value, in this case the console.log("hi") is printted twice, and i don't know why it is happening, i try with conditional operators, but it always renders twice.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import SearchAPI from "./SearchAPI";

export default function Search() {
  const searchRef = React.createRef();

  const [contentSearched, setContentSearched] = useState("");

  const handleSendSearch = e => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      setContentSearched(searchRef.current.value);
    } else {
      setContentSearched("");
    }
  };

  return (
    <section className="searchbox-wrap">
      <input
        onKeyPress={handleSendSearch}
        ref={searchRef}
        placeholder="Search for a movie..."
        type="text"
        className="searchbox"
      />
      {contentSearched !== "" ? console.log("Hi") : <></>} -> Here i have the problem
    </section>
  );
}
```

**Console**

```
Hi Search.js:19 
Hi Search.js:19
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I thoroughly understand the issue, it probably logs on the initial render, then when you click enter it logs again, correct? Which if it does that is correct

Comment: @AlexK that is correct, in my console appear two hi, i think the initial render it's the problem because the function is executed when a condition is met. In this case, the press of the key Enter

Comment: you could try as `{contentSearched !== ""  &&  contentSearched !== undefined  ? console.log("Hi") : <></>} `

Comment: When component first time rendered, the state contentSearched maybe is undefined, so `contentSearched !== "" ?` also return true.

Comment: @Kuo-hsuanHsu contentSearched never is undefined, because i give a initial state that is "" (empty string)

Answer (score 0):

try to create a more simple component like this. You should see more than 1 console log after update. I think that maybe there's no issue.

```
function Test() {
  const [clickedTimes, setClickedTimes] = React.useState(0);
  console.log('rendering')
  function clickHandler() {
    console.log('clicked triggered')
    setClickedTimes(clickedTimes + 1)
  }
  return <span onClick={clickHandler}>clicked: {clickedTimes}</span>
}
```

I hope this can help you